# Hide the html link tag if it's empty with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to hide the html link tag if the href value is `#`, otherwise it should remain shown. The href values are retrieved from the database in a PHP loop.

```
<li>
    <a class="linkedes" href="http//:Someurl ....">LINK</a>
    <a class="linkedes" href="#">FACEBOOK</a>
    <a class="linkedes" href="#">TWITTER</a>
    <a class="linkedes" href="#">INSTAGRAM</a>
    <a class="linkedes" href="http//:Someurl ....">PLAYSTORE</a>
    <a class="linkedes" href="#">GITHUB</a>
    <a class="linkedes" href="#">YOUTUBE</a></li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jQuery to find and hide like so:

```
$('a[href="#"').hide();
```

Put that in a script tag and execute it after the page has loaded:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a[href="#"').hide();
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much sir.

Answer (score 3):

You can use css [attribute selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) to add specific style to matching elements

```css
a[href='#'] {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<li>
  <a class="linkedes" href="http//:Someurl ....">LINK</a>
  <a class="linkedes" href="#">FACEBOOK</a>
  <a class="linkedes" href="#">TWITTER</a>
  <a class="linkedes" href="#">INSTAGRAM</a>
  <a class="linkedes" href="http//:Someurl ....">PLAYSTORE</a>
  <a class="linkedes" href="#">GITHUB</a>
  <a class="linkedes" href="#">YOUTUBE</a></li>
```

Comment: Thank you very much sir.

Answer (score 1):

Try this: first, get all the links using `getElementsByClassName`, then use `Array.prototype.forEach` to iterate the links, adding a `style` attribute to hide the link if the `href` matches `#`.

```js
const allLinks = document.getElementsByClassName('linkedes');
[].forEach.call(allLinks,link => {
  if (link.getAttribute('href') === "#") {
    link.style = "display:none;";
  }
});
```

```html
<a class="linkedes" href="http//:Someurl ....">LINK</a>
    <a class="linkedes" href="#">FACEBOOK</a>
    <a class="linkedes" href="#">TWITTER</a>
    <a class="linkedes" href="#">INSTAGRAM</a>
    <a class="linkedes" href="http//:Someurl ....">PLAYSTORE</a>
    <a class="linkedes" href="#">GITHUB</a>
    <a class="linkedes" href="#">YOUTUBE</a></li>
```

Comment: Thank you very much sir.